# containstable does not give all the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run below query, it didn't give all results.
I have data which is issued in July and Oct. both title field includes word "bank". 
But result only show july one.

```
Title:Bank of Ireland  - issued in Oct
Title:Ulster Bank      - issued in July

SELECT     [KEY], RANK
FROM         CONTAINSTABLE(tblDB, title, '"bank"')
ORDER BY [KEY] DESC
```

I was trying to "Bank" instead "bank". It doesn't work.
Can anybody explain what is CONTAINSTABLE?

I read couple of article, it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

"Returns a table of zero, one, or more rows for those columns containing character-based data types for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases, the proximity of words within a certain distance of one another, or weighted matches. CONTAINSTABLE can only be referenced in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement as if it were a regular table name.

Queries using CONTAINSTABLE specify contains-type full-text queries that return a relevance ranking value (RANK) and full-text key (KEY) for each row. The CONTAINSTABLE function uses the same search conditions as the CONTAINS predicate."

Tell me what you are trying to do and I will be able to help more?

Comment: thanks I rebuild fully-text index now. Hopfully this one solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a description of CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx).  Try rebuilding your full-text index and then perform the search again.